# Prove $f^{−1}(T − Y ) = S − f^{-1}(Y )$.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I could use some help here:

Let $f:S\rightarrow T$ be a function. If $Y \subseteq T$, we define the inverse image of $Y$ to be $f^{−1} (Y ) = \{x ∈ S : f(x) ∈ Y \}$. Prove $f^{−1}(T − Y ) = S − f^{-1}(Y )$.

I start by supposing $x\in f^{-1}(T-Y)\subseteq S$ which gives $f(x)\in T-Y$, and it seems like $f(x)$, the set $T$, and the set $S$ can somehow be transformed into $x$, $S$, and $f^{-1}(Y)$ respectively via $f^{-1}$, but I'm not sure how to do this. Doing so would prove $f^{−1}(T − Y ) \subseteq S − f^{-1}(Y )$ and then doing the proof in reverse would show the reverse, thus proving equality.

Comment: $x\in f^{-1}(T-Y)\in S$? What does that mean? $x\in f^{-1}(T-Y)$ is certainly meaningful but $f^{-1}(T-Y)\in S$?? both sides are sets, and one does not expect $S$ to be a set with sets as elements.

Comment: $f(x)\in T-Y\;\Longrightarrow\,f(x)\notin Y\;\Longrightarrow\,x\notin f^{-1}(Y)\;\Longrightarrow\,x\in S-f^{-1}(Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

The following statements are equivalent for a function $f:S\to T$:

- $x\in f^{-1}(T-Y)$
- $f(x)\in T-Y$
- $f(x)\notin Y$
- $x\notin f^{-1}(Y)$
- $x\in S-f^{-1}(Y)$

Looking at the first and last bullet we can conclude that:$$f^{-1}(T-Y)=S-f^{-1}(Y)$$

---

To be well equipped for problems like this put the following rule in your math luggage:$$x\in f^{-1}(A)\iff f(x)\in A$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y\in f^{-1}(T-Y)$. Since $$\begin{array} 1f^{-1}(T-Y)&=\{s\in S: f(s)\in T-Y\}\\&=\{s\in S:f(s)\in T\text{ and }f(s)\notin Y\}\\&=f^{-1}(T)-f^{-1}(Y)\\&=S-f^{-1}(Y)\end{array}$$

Comment: @downvoter - since Steve seems to be new to MSE, perhaps consider explaining what qualm you have with the answer so it can be amended :)

Comment: First: you have proved everything in lines 2-5. Second: The second direction is completely wrong.

Comment: Indeed. @Steve - note that you show the equality in the first few lines without using subjectivity, which should tell you that either A) you know subjectivity *is* needed so your proof is flawed, or else B) Your proof is actually correct, and so the subjectivity assumption and second half of the proof is at best superfluous.

Comment: Both great points. I've made an edit to my post.